# Слайдер Swiper. Настройка scroll и pagination

Tags: javascript, слайдер, swiper

Цель у меня это сделать так чтоб отображалось по 3,5 слайда на активную зону (Это делается параметром slidesPerView). Ползунок (scroll) соответствовал активному слайду, то есть был по ширине и под активным слайдом. Вот как это сделать ?

Пытаюсь создать такой же слайдер как тут https://www.rolex.com/de/watches/air-king.html
[пример анимационный](https://gyazo.com/d5f33ad6761b2da0732a69f8b5999d0e)

```js
 var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 3.5,
       spaceBetween: 30,
        scrollbar: {
            el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
            hide: false,
        },
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
          return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
        },
      },
    });
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;

  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
/* custmm bullets style */
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#000;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  color:#fff;
  background: #007aff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">        
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
     <!-- Add scrollbar  -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавить ширину слайда в CSS `((100% - 2 х margin-right)/3)`. Например:

```
.swiper-slide { width: 27%;}.
```